# windows 7 not starting after installing ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, dual-boot, windows-7

I have installed ubuntu 13.04. grub menu is showing both the options windows 7 and ubuntu also.but when i click on windows 7 its just showing black screen and cursor blinking for long time but windows 7 does not start while ubuntu is working fine please help me...

Comment: This would be a a Windows issue. Run through the recover options otherwise, reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

This may be an issue in your GRUB menu.
Try the `Recommended Repair` of the [Boot-Repair tool.](http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/)

[image]